# Bluetooth Module multi connection

Tags: module, bluetooth, raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy, raspberry-pi2

I was wondering if anyone knows what the best bluetooth module would be that can support up to 7 devices simultaneously. I have a project where all the devices will only have to receive information. I am using a raspberry pi b+ for the project and am wanting to keep the price low.

Comment: I've used one from IOGear that was able to handle 7 simultaneous connections with no issues.

Comment: Tim thank you for the response, do you know which one it was?

Comment: GBU521W6 is the model number.  Unfortunately it's not really cheap.  I bought 2 other ones from China and neither was able to handle 7.  None of them advertise what the limit is, so you have to just buy and test.